# Executar php artisan em um diretorio diferente

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Como executar o comando:

```
php artisan ...
```

Em um diretório diferente de forma que os arquivos gerados fiquem na pasta que eu definir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso vai depender do comando ao qual você deseje executar, mas vamos partir do pressuposto que você queira executar uma `migration`, você consegue definir o `path`(Caminho) desta forma:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/app/database/migrations/relations
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641606/laravel-running-migrations-on-app-database-migrations-folder-recursively)

> 1 - Lembrando que você deve esta dentro diretório onde esta o arquivo
>   *artisan*
>  
>   2 - E o executável do *php* deve esta nas variáveis de ambiente

Mas se você quiser executar o comando em outra pasta, basca colocar o caminho completo de cada arquivo, como por exemplo:

```
c:\bin\php.exe c:\meu_projeto\artisan migrate --path=c:\meu_projeto\migrations
```

No exemplo, meu executável do php esta na pasta "bin" na raiz do `c:`, enquanto meu projeto esta na pasta "meu_projeto" e dentro de "meu_projeto" as `migrations`.

> Isso gera muito trabalho, então é preferível entrar na pasta onde esta
>   o arquivo `artisan` e colocar o executável do php nas variáveis de
>   ambiente.